# how to prevent system() function from printing output in the browser?

Tags: php, shell, command-line, curl, system

I'm using [`system()`](http://php.net/system) PHP function to run some curl commands like this `system("curl command here",$output);` but it displays results on screen. Any way to avoid this output?

Comment: maybe use `@` in front of it? `@system`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?  Per the docs you reference, that's the ordinary use of `system()` in PHP (that is, to execute a command and "_display the output_").  Yes, there are ways around it, but there may be a finer-grained approach appropriate for your problem that doesn't involve `system()`.

Comment: @Shvelo That suppresses errors, not output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You coud try using output buffering.

```
ob_start();
system("curl command here",$output);
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using the wrong function for that. According to the docs:

> system() is just like the C version of the function in that it executes the given command and outputs the result.

So it always outputs. Use [`exec`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/exec) instead which does return (and not output) the programs output:

```
$last =  exec("curl command here", $output, $status);
$output = implode("\n", $output);
```

Or (just for completeness) use [output buffering<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
system("curl command here", $status);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either modify the command string and append " 1>/dev/null 2>&1" or - more elegantly - execute the process with a [pipe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) (see example #2).

For a more refined control over the process' file handles, you can also use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Answer (score 1):

The [system](http://php.net/system) function displays the output from your command, so you're out of luck there.

What you want is to change `system` for [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). That function will not display the command's output.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should use [PHP curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: well I'm forced to use it as I'm coding a backend script running as root on a server. The server where it's running has like a sandbox where cURL is disabled and even socket_create() is not working fine!

Comment: That's strange, you have the root access and cannot enable curl?

Comment: Also, running php as a backend script ... it does not matter how noisy  (as you unlikely view it realtime anyway)